# How to group by date with the column's date-type Timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql

Database is mysql. The table likes that:

```
Create table Persons (_id int8 primary key, name varchar, birthday long);
```

the birthday is the birthday's timestamp.

so I want to select the data that group by date, it means that the result should be one record  for one day

```
select sum(_id) from Persons group by ....
```

Who can help me, please?

Comment: Is there any specific reason for picking datatype of birthday as 'long'?

Comment: is there any data type called long in mysql?
i know about longblob and longtext

Answer (score 1):

Try this way,

```
select sum(_id) FROM Persons GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(birthday, '%Y%m%d')
```

Answer (score 0):

perhaps:

```
select sum(_id) from Persons group by DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(birthday), '%d-%m-%Y')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select sum(_id) from Persons group by date_format(birthday,'%y-%m-%d')
```